# Install the default weather gadget on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, desktop-gadget, weather

I have uninstalled the default weather gadget by accident (right-click any gadget and press "uninstall").

Now I want to get it back (the 3rd party gadgets don't seem as attractive as the standard one), but I don't know how.

Unfortunately, this folder `C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Sidebar\Gadgets` only contains the 3rd-party gadgets.

I was able to find it here (on another system) `C:\Program Files\Windows Sidebar\Gadgets\Weather.Gadget`, so I copied them to the same directory on my machine, hoping it would do the trick.

It didn't, because the gadget doesn't show up in the list.

Can someone suggest a way to install the default weather gadget back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Click on start.
2. Type in "Restore Gadgets" in the start box.
3. Click on "Restore desktop gadgets installed with Windows".